# SSRS and Crystal Reports

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports

I have a question about SSRS and Crystal Reports.  I am a student, and I am thinking about a career as a reports developer.  I've noticed that there are plenty of jobs for Crystal Report developers.  I am familiar with SSRS, and I will soon have a lot of experience using it.  However, I have never used Crystal Reports.

Is Crystal Reports significantly different from SSRS, or are they essentially the same program?  If I know SSRS, would it be difficult to learn Crystal Reports?

-Neil

Comment: This question doesn't fit for the `SO`... if you have any problem in development or issues ask for solutions.

Comment: Report developer here (since 1995).  Don't be *just* a report developer; it gets a bit tedious at times.  Add other skill sets and tools to your repertoire--you'll be more employable and have more employment options.

Comment: I think the general perception is that Crystal Reports is in decline while SSRS is rising in use.  It's common to hear of projects converting Crystal to SSRS, but going the other way or new Crystal projects seem very rare. In your particular labor market this may reflect in a shortage of candidates for Crystal work as people try to get ahead of the curve. The work would tend to be maintenance/fixes, and you would expect it to slowly dry up.

Comment: I agree with Mike here that Crystal Reports is in decline. There are many new technologies being released that are built on existing platforms, like Visual Studio for instance, that are not as bug-ridden, incompatible, and difficult to deal with. I think minimal effort to learning CR would be necessary to get your foot in the door but you will need to gain some general knowledge with server maintenance, 'SQL', and deploying services to understand what can go wrong, unless you expect your superiors to handle those problems for you.

Answer (score 2):

Crystal Reports is deprecated BI software (2013 last updated) that has not been updated since 2013 and it has a significantly high TCO bundled into Business Objects and CAL cost while SSRS is free.